# Were Jupiter-C's really given code names based on the word "Huntsville"?

Tags: launch, explorer-1

In the video [Explorer 1 Preparation and Launch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kw_ulaECjSg) around the ten-minute mark the narrator says:

> This particular Jupiter C, it’s serial number was 29, and that was coded in the missile. You see on the first stage just below the service structure the letters UE, those are the second, and ninth letters in the word Huntsville.

Is this known to be true? What about the pairs 7/8, 17/18 and 27/28, which would be indistinguishable (within a pair) and would all end in "L"?

[image: Jupiter C coded "UE"]

Cued at `09:47`

Comment: Wikipedia discusses it, including the duplicate L, but it’s “citation needed”. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jupiter-C#Encrypted_serial_number

Comment: @BobJacobsen Citation added :^)

Comment: @AlexHajnal that's excellent!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that was in fact the code but with one slight change:

```
H  U  N  T  S  V  I  L  E  X
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0
```

Redstone was the first (or sole) stage of the Redstone, Jupiter-A, Jupiter-C, and Juno-1 rockets.  The HUNTSVILEX code was used during the initial development of the Redstone booster.

Sources:

- [Science.gov Trivia Question of the Day: April 15, 2014](https://www.science.gov/communications/trivia.html) (Science.gov)
- [Jupiter C Fact Sheet](https://web.archive.org/web/20180619140944/http://www.spaceline.org/rocketsum/jupiter-c.html) (Cliff Lethbridge / Spaceline.org)
- [SP-4402 Origins of NASA Names](https://history.nasa.gov/SP-4402/ch1.htm) (NASA)
  This source states that only 1-9 were represented (no X).
- [Redstone family](https://space.skyrocket.de/doc_lau_fam/redstone.htm) (Gunter's Space Page)
  Lists codes for many of the launches, verifying that X was, in fact used.
- [Photo of the fifth Redstone launch](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Fifth_Redstone_launch.jpg) (NASA via Wikimedia Commons)
  The fifth flight but the sixth vehicle, serial number RS-6 (encoded as `RSXV`).

Comment: Aha, very nice! And it seems I can't count, otherwise I would have realized that "E" is not the 9th letter in the unmodified spelling.

Comment: The first link is a US government page (and links to the second) but I'm looking for a more authoritative source.